# Number of parameters in CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm trying to understand how CNN works. In doing so, one of the things I am trying to solve is this:

1. Let's say we have an input X of dimensions = `(32, 32, 3)`; in this,
   n_h=n_w=32 and n_c =3. where n_h and n_w are the height and width, respectively,
   and 3 is the number of channels.
2. Let's say we apply 1 convolution pass, i.e., passing it through `8`
   filters (f) of size of 5 i.e., `(5, 5, 3)` with a stride `(s) of 1` +
   activation, we would get "weight" matrix of size `(28, 28, 8)`.

The weight matrix shape is determined by this: `((n_h-f)/s) + 1` = ((32-5)/1) + 1 
and number of channels for the weight matrix = number of filters.

In my understanding, the number of parameters for the "weight" matrix of size `(28, 28, 8)` should be

`(5*5*3 + 1) * 8 = (filter + bias) * number of filters` = `608`.

Instead the value is reported as `208` with an weight matrix size of `6272`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured this out - the value given in the course is wrong.

The value of `(filter*filter*channels + 1) * num_of_filters` makes sense!